# Populating a listbox with search results from a SQL query in ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The idea behind the program is for a user to enter a title they would like to search for and then click on the search button. The program should then display the search results in a listbox. The current code populates the listbox with all the available titles when the from loads but when you search for a title the listbox stays the same. How can I avoid the population of the listbox when the form loads and how do I only display the search result when the user clicks the search button?

Here is the C# code I have written:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Project2
{
    public partial class ProductSelection : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public SqlConnection conn1;
        public DataSet ds;
        public SqlDataAdapter adap;
        string DVDToRent;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Hanno\Desktop\CMPG\CMPG212\Project 2\Project2\Project2\App_Data\Stock.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Title FROM StockTable WHERE Title LIKE '%" + Session["DVDToRent"] + "%' AND CopiesAvailable = 'True'"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;

                        con.Open();

                        lstCustomers.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        lstCustomers.DataTextField = "Title";
                        lstCustomers.DataValueField = "ID";
                        lstCustomers.DataBind();

                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DVDToRent = tbSearch.Text; 
            Session["DvDToRent"] = tbSearch.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

and the ASP.NET markup for the listbox:

```
<div class="formSearch" runat="server"> 
        <div class ="form-group">
            <h2 class="auto-style2">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Search for a DVD:"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Search Results:"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:ListBox ID="lstCustomers" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="400px"></asp:ListBox>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Step away and learn about SQL injection before you continue on.

Comment: @mxmissile noted but this is for a Uni project so I don't need to worry about SQL injection being used against me.

Comment: You loading the data on Page_Load.  Why aren't you reloading new data (based on the search results) after the BtnClick?

Comment: I'd create a new function ````LoadData()```` that you can call on initial Page_Load and then you can also call in the BtnClick event.

Comment: And obviously, using a parameter for the text input is a lot safer than taking their input straight into your query.

Comment: @JohnPete22 Okay so I've tried creating a new function with a parameter. When the form loads the listbox is then populated with all the titles(Which is weird because the parameter is empty) but when I enter something in the search textbox and click the search button nothing changes in the listbox.

Comment: You understand what a LIKE statement is, right? Go execute a query by itself in the DB, having a LIKE '%%'  (that is your initial search, string.empty).  You're getting the expected result.  Then go execute with what you searched.  And what is the point of the Session variable? Are you using it on other pages...if not, it's pointless here unless you plan to reload the search results when the user leaves and then comes back.